# Dynamically eager loading deep relationships with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm currently working on an API using the following stack;

- Symfony (3)
- FOSRestBundle
- Fractal

I'm wanting to integrate the ability to specify, via query parameter, which relationships to include when retrieving an entity/collection, e.g;

```
[GET] /users?include=friends.addresses
```

[Fractal comes with the ability to handle includes](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/#including-data) however, as this happens around the serialization point of the response building, each related entity is retrieved via lazy loading, thus triggering additional queries.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine, when retrieving a collection, to dynamically also retrieve relationships specified? Ive seen [the following from the Doctrine docs which shows how to dynamically change the fetch mode](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) however this only seems to work with associations on the target entity (`friends` in the example above) and not deeper relations (`addresses` of `friends` in the example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can "preload" relations by joining them in rather than letting the lazy loading mechanism handle it. An idea could be to create a service that creates a query builder based on your criteria. This is a crude snippet of what I mean:

```php
class EagerService
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function resolveIncludes($class, $alias, $includes) 
    {
        // Parse includes into an array
        if (strpos($includes, '.') !== false) {
            $relations = explode('.', $includes);
        } else {
            $relations = [$includes];
        }

        // The next relation is owned by the previous one, so we keep track of the previous relation
        $previousRelation = $alias;
        $qb = $em->getRepository($class)->getQueryBuilder($previousRelation);
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            // Add inner joins to the query builder referencing the new relation
            $qb->innerJoin("{$previousRelation}.{$relation}", $relation);
            $previousRelation = $relation;
        }

        // Return query builder or the result of the query
        return $qb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like the best solution so I'll build upon it

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I saw I forgot to change `$str` around to `$includes` so I fixed that.

Comment: hm.. it would be nice to create a package for this purpose.